# Value for x such that |(x-y)| is minimum

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

I have a list

```
Y={y1,y2,y3,...,yn}
```

And I would need to find x such that

> `Abs[x-Y[[i]]]` for all $y_i$ in $Y$ is minimum.

I unfortunatly can't remember my highschool Statistics courses where this function was defined.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean to minimize the sum over the `|x-y_i|`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to ask in Mathematica (the software) forum? Isn't this rather about Maths (math.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: That was a fast accept. By the way, the value that minimizes the sum of absolute deviations is called the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#An_optimality_property), and using Mathematica's built-in function for it will probably be a better idea.

Comment: @RahulNarain How do you and Nasser know it is about sum? :)

Comment: @Kuba I feel more confident in my guess now that the asker has accepted Nasser's answer!

Comment: @RahulNarain You are right. Too bad that OP does not care about adding this information. -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[x]
npts = 10;
y = RandomReal[{0, 1}, npts];
z = x /. FindMinimum[Total[Abs[#] & /@ (x - y)], x][[2]];
ListPlot[{{{1, z}, {npts, z}}, y}, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Appendix**
Comments above said to use `Median` for this. But this test shows result of `Median` and what I have above is not the same. Tried it on different random lists:

```
ClearAll[x]
npts = 10;
minAbs[y_] := Module[{x}, x /. FindMinimum[Total[Abs[#] & /@ (x - y)], x][[2]]];
z = Table[y = RandomReal[{0, 1}, npts]; {minAbs[y], Median[y]}, {10}];
Map[Abs@Differences[#] &, z]
```

gives

```
{{0.0210295415415782}, {0.0034994693789796}, {0.000485836594898592}, \
{0.00186973168510612}, {0.000737313633257242}, {0.00571989492676428}, \
{0.00631402466773001}, {0.0449264216282105}, {0.0881414864517821}, \
{0.0000334557733309149}}
```

So, there is a difference? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: When there is an even number of values, any value between the middle two is a minimizer; in other words, the median is not unique. Try comparing the value of `Total[Abs[...` on both your result and the median. Then try the whole thing again with `npts = 11`.